# Ipad Gmail links no longer open

Tags: ipad, gmail

I am enquiring about my wife's gmail account on her iPad.
Until recently all links worked satisfactorily and opened in Google easily.
Suddenly this has ceased and whenever she clicks on a link in gmail, google opens but it goes to the default page and does not open to the link.
I have been through all the settings that I can find but i don't seem to be able to get it working again.

Comment: Please add your iOS version and iPad model. Are you looking for other mail clients too? Also, can you configure to open links in Safari?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  One suggestion on the web was deleting the gmail app from my iPad and downloading it again.  I tried that, but I couldn't download the app again because it said the new version of gmail didn't work on my old iPad.
So now we know why the links weren't working.

So then I went into Google on my iPad and opened my gmail account from there.  It's not as convenient as using the app, but at least the links work fine.